# How to define a supremum on a set?

Tags: isabelle

I'm trying to describe a type system of a programming language. It has a common subtype for any types (VoidType) and a common supertype for any types (AnyType):

```
datatype type =
  VoidType |
  AnyType |
  BooleanType |
  EBooleanType |
  RealType |
  IntegerType |
  UnlimNatType |
  StringType

fun subtype_strict_fun :: "type ⇒ type ⇒ bool" (infix "<:sf" 55) where
  "_ <:sf VoidType = False"
| "VoidType <:sf _ = True"
| "AnyType <:sf _ = False"
| "_ <:sf AnyType = True"
| "BooleanType <:sf EBooleanType = True"
| "IntegerType <:sf RealType = True"
| "UnlimNatType <:sf IntegerType = True"
| "UnlimNatType <:sf RealType = True"
| "_ <:sf _ = False"

definition subtype_fun :: "type ⇒ type ⇒ bool" (infix "<:f" 55) where
  "x <:f y ≡ x = y ∨ x <:sf y"
```

I'm trying to instantinate `type` as `ccpo`:

```
instantiation type :: ccpo
begin

definition "less_eq = subtype_fun"
definition "less = subtype_strict_fun"

lemma subtype_strict_eq_subtype:
  "(x <:sf y) = (x <:f y ∧ ¬ y <:f x)"
  by (cases x; cases y; simp add: subtype_fun_def)

lemma subtype_refl:
  "x <:f x"
  by (simp add: subtype_fun_def)

lemma subtype_trans:
  "x <:f y ⟹ y <:f z ⟹ x <:f z"
  by (cases x; cases y; cases z; simp add: subtype_fun_def)

lemma subtype_antisym:
  "x <:f y ⟹ y <:f x ⟹ x = y"
  by (cases x; cases y; simp add: subtype_fun_def)

instance
  apply intro_classes
  apply (simp add: less_eq_type_def less_type_def subtype_strict_eq_subtype)
  apply (simp add: less_eq_type_def less_type_def subtype_refl)
  apply (metis less_eq_type_def subtype_trans)
  apply (metis less_eq_type_def subtype_antisym)

end
```

Could you suggest how to define a supremum function `Sup :: OCL.type set ⇒ OCL.type`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `OCL.type` is finite, so all sets of type `OCL.type set` are finite, too. Moreover, there is also a top element in your hierarchy. Therefore, you can define the `Sup` operation simply by folding `sup` over the given set. The locale `comm_monoid_set` provides the necessary infrastructure. First, instantiate the type classes `semilattice_sup` and `order_top`. Then interpret `comm_monoid_set`:

```
interpretation ocl': abel_semigroup sup "top :: OCL.type" <proof>
interpretation ocl: comm_monoid_set sup "top :: OCL.type" <proof>
```

This generates the folded `sup` operation over sets under the name `ocl.F`. So,

```
definition "Sup_ocl = ocl.F id"
```

gives you a definition for the `Sup` operation. This is a general construction that works for any finite upper semilattice with a top element. But it will not give you any dedicated setup for reasoning about the `OCL.type` hierarchy in particular. You'll have to derive appropriate rules yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's really cool! The 2nd argument for `comm_monoid_set` must be `VoidType` because it's neutral element for `sup`.

Comment: Could you suggest please, what approach should be used for infinite types? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46618400/how-to-define-sup-for-an-inductive-datatype

Comment: You cannot compute suprema for infinite sets unless you know something about the structure of the infinite set.